# Why can´t I make a goodlooking napolitan style pizza dough?

Tags: dough, flour, pizza

I know you have to use a oven that can get to at least 800°F, and I am using a home  integrated kitchen oven, but I can´t get any closer to a good-looking pizza than this

[image: resulting pizza]

It taste delicious but I want something like this

[image: Goodlooking napolitan style pizza] (or at least something similar).

The ingredients I use are:

- 450g All purpose flour
- 230ml water
- 4g fresh yeast
- 5g salt
- 2g sugar

I also use a round metal pizza plate with holes to prepare the pizza because I don´t have palets to move the pizza (like this one [image: metal pizza plate with holes]).

I hope someone can tell me how to improve my technice, I am working on a homemade oven that can´t get to 900°F, to take the oven´s lacks of temperature off the equation, so I guess it won´t be an stopper anytime soon.

Comment: And how hot can your curent oven go?

Comment: How long did you ferment the dough, and at what temperature (room temp or cold-ferment)?

Comment: @Stephie  I use a metal baking plate, like the one you can see it on the second picture (edited question). For the record I can´t measure how hot my oven can go, but I would say that it can to to 600°F at most.

Comment: @NSGod it was fermented at room temp for 4 to 5 hours. But several tries before has been fermented up to 8 to 10 hours (even a day being fermented) and the result is almost the same.

Comment: ~600F is ~300C - that shouldn’t be a showstopper. Hotter is better, but within reason. (If you can live without the spotting.) Without going into details, I feel  looking into the dough preparation/fermentation, handling and thermal mass of your oven could be the most important parameters. And maybe cooking time, as stated below by Max.

Comment: One more question, just to be sure: “fresh yeast” as in the soft greyish-brown mass that is stored in the fridge and stays good for just a few weeks, not a fresh package of dried yeast granules? Double-checking because of the ratios.

Comment: @Stephie Fresh yeast like the brown soft mass.

Comment: I'm by no means a pizza making expert (although maybe an eating one), but my first approaches to get a fluffier, Napolitan dough would be: longer fermentation (up to 24 hours), less topping mass and broader crust. If you can, you might also get a pizza stone for your oven to hold the heat better.

Comment: How do you shape your pizza? Do you roll the dough? I ask because your edge looks very thin. My oven goes to around 465F/240C but is fan assisted but my pizza looks closer to the 2nd pic than the first. Hand stretching the pizza and leaving a thicker edge may help you.

Comment: @JohnW I will try with 20 hour fermentation

Comment: @Spagirl I don´t use a roll, I use my hands, maybe the shaping technique is not well performed, I am gonna try to get a thicker edge to see if it works.

Comment: important question: did you pre-heat the oven? for how long? Do you have an oven thermometer, to make sure you're getting the correct temperature before putting the pizza in?

Comment: @Luciano Last time I tried, I preheated the oven 30 mins before putting the pizza, I got a better result but still not what I want. I dont have a thermometer.

Answer (score 1):

It does not look baked enough.

Are you using a pizza stone, that might help a little bit.

You could fire up the broiler mode on your oven to crisp up the top of your pizza.

Keep an eye on it so it does not burn.

Comment: I use a pizza plate to handle the prepared pizza before cooking, should I use another plate, warm it on the oven and then put the pizza on the warmed plate? (while I buy the pizza stone)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have the right kind of flour and I let it leaven the right time depending on the above flour, after I portion the dough for individual pizzas I make them again in a round shape by rolling in two opposite directions and letting them rest with the seed facing downwards.

To spread, the principle to follow is to start from the center and let the air go towards the edge, which needs not to be flattened. This can be obtained only by hand and not with a rolling pin.

Considering the baking, if you don't have a stone I suggest to use a perforated tray. I personally bake the dough alone for some minutes, also in order to detach the dough in some points where it was thinner.
At this point, you need to know your own oven and find out when to add the sauce and the cheese by trial and error ;)